# I Just want to reduce array of object into one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, reduce

This is my array of object.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
    { banner: "", intersitial: "", native: "", openVoice: "" },
    { banner: "", intersitial: "", native: "", openVoice: "" },
    { banner: "", intersitial: "", native: "", openVoice: "" },
]);
```

Also this is my submit method

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    const bannerData = data.map((ele) => {
      return ele.banner;
    });

    const nativeData = data.map((ele) => {
      return ele.native;
    });

    const intersitialData = data.map((ele) => {
      return ele.intersitial;
    });

    const openViaData = data.map((ele) => {
      return ele.openVoice;
    });

    const newData = {
      appId: id,
      banner: bannerData,
      intersitial: intersitialData,
      native: nativeData,
      openVia: openViaData,
    };
    axios
      .post(`${url}/ads/create-ads`, newData)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("res", res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error", err);
      });
  };
```

I have used four map functions then data pass in single object.
Basically I want 1 reduce method

Comment: come on. please no images. take text instead and add your code.

Comment: please click on first and 2nd link [this is my array of object] thanks

Comment: @ZeeshanAkram Please see this link for why images of data/code aren't encouraged: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: No worries @NinaScholz i have posted my code thanks

Comment: @NinaScholz please check it i have post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All in one reduce method should be like this:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  const newData = data.reduce((prev, current) => ({
    ...prev,
    banner: [...prev.banner, current.banner],
    intersitial: [...prev.intersitial, current.intersitial],
    native: [...prev.native, current.native],
    openVia: [...prev.openVia, current.openVoice] 
  }), {
    appId: id,
    banner: [],
    intersitial: [],
    native: [],
    openVia: [],
  });

  axios
    .post(`${url}/ads/create-ads`, newData)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("res", res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error", err);
    });
};
```

You can pass the initial value with some empty arrays and fill them on every iteration of the reduce method.

[Array.reduce usage and syntax here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: thanks for your answer @crls_b. One thing more i want to reverse this object into array of object.